# Get information about an invoice and return the number of invoice items on it with a single SELECT comand

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using the chinook database and sqlite3. My goal is to return a list of invoices with the invoice id, invoice date and the number of items on the invoice for a specific customer. The first two are pretty simple,

```
SELECT InvoiceId, InvoiceDate 
FROM invoices 
WHERE CustomerId = 2;
```

returns:

```
1  |2009-01-01 00:00:00    
12 |2009-02-11 00:00:00    
67 |2009-10-12 00:00:00    
196|2011-05-19 00:00:00    
219|2011-08-21 00:00:00    
241|2011-11-23 00:00:00    
293|2012-07-13 00:00:00
```

However, the invoice line items are in another table.  I can count the ones that correspond to specific invoices with:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM invoice_items 
WHERE Invoiceid = 12;
```

which returns `14`

But I want to return a list like:

```
1 |2009-01-01 00:00:00|2    
12|2009-02-11 00:00:00|14
```

Comment: You should use SQL's JOIN 
http://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/sqlite-inner-join.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an inner join on your query; it will look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    invoices.InvoiceId, invoices.InvoiceDate,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(items.ID)) AS Items 
FROM 
    invoices
JOIN 
    invoice_items AS items ON invoices.ID = itemsID
GROUP BY invoices.InvoiceId
```

Of course I'm guessing the names of your `ID` columns

Comment: Not sure why you would need the DISTINCT, COUNT(1) would work just as well, but DISTINCT should make it more obvious to the reader of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try a subquery like the following:

`select invoiceid, invoicedate,
    (select count(*) from invoice_items where invoiceid = i.invoiceid) as CountInvoiceItems
from invoices`

to get all the results, otherwise you can add your where clause back in for just invoice 12.

Answer (score 0):

To get invoices of a specific customer you should use join

here's an example:

```
SELECT InvoiceId, InvoiceDate, count(*) 
FROM invoices 
JOIN invoice_items ON invoices.InvoiceId=invoice_items.invoiceid 
GROUP BY invoices.InvoiceId
```